# Get all friends of a given user on twitter with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Using tweepy I am able to return all of my friends using a cursor.  Is it possible to specify another user and get all of their friends?

```
user = api.get_user('myTwitter')
print "Retreiving friends for", user.screen_name
for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items():
 print "\n", friend.screen_name
```

Which prints a list of all my friends, however if I change the first line
to another twitter user it still returns my friends.  How can I get friends for any given user using tweepy?

```
#first line is changed to
user = api.get_user('otherUsername') #still returns my friends
```

Additionally `user.screen_name` when printed **WILL** return `otherUsername`

The question [Get All Follower IDs in Twitter by Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431807/get-all-follower-ids-in-twitter-by-tweepy) does essentially what I am looking for however it returns only a count of ID's.  If I remove the `len()` function I will I can iterate through a list of user IDs, but is it possible to get screen names `@twitter`,`@stackoverflow`, `@etc.....`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get All Follower IDs in Twitter by Tweepy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431807/get-all-follower-ids-in-twitter-by-tweepy). The variable `ids` in the accepted answer contains all IDs, the answerer prints its length but you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I don't necessarily believe this to be duplicate question, I am looking for the twitter handles or `screen_name`, not IDs which is what is returned in the question I included it in the question itself as reference since my code is essentially the same

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `ids` variable from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17490816/3440302) you referenced in the other answer to get the the id of the followers of a given person, and extend it to get the screen names of all of the followers using Tweepy's [`api.lookup_users`](https://gitorious.org/tweepy/mainline/source/55633082b16c92d51ed906f5cc2147e71a20102f:tweepy/api.py#L163) method:

```
import time
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(..., ...)
auth.set_access_token(..., ...)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

ids = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name="McDonalds").pages():
    ids.extend(page)
    time.sleep(60)

screen_names = [user.screen_name for user in api.lookup_users(user_ids=ids)]
```

Comment: This solution did what I was looking for.

Comment: i get this error when i try this, does anyone know if something has changed?    thanks                             tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Too many terms specified in query.', u'code': 18}]

Comment: It only takes 100 ids at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
# import the module
import tweepy
  
# assign the values accordingly
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
  
# authorization of consumer key and consumer secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  
# set access to user's access key and access secret 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
  
# calling the api 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
  
# the screen_name of the targeted user
screen_name = "TwitterIndia"
  
# printing the latest 20 friends of the user
for friend in api.friends(screen_name):
    print(friend.screen_name)
```

for more details see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-api-friends-in-tweepy/