# tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Text parameter is missing.', u'code': 38}]

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

I am using `tweepy` twitter api for python, while using it i got some error,
I am not able to use `send_direct_message(user/screen_name/user_id, text)` this method

Here is my code:-

```
import tweepy
consumer_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

API = tweepy.API(auth)

user = API.get_user('SSPendse')
screen_name="CJ0495"
id = 773436067231956992
text="Message Which we have to send must have maximum 140 characters, If it is Greater then the message will be truncated upto 140 characters...."
# re = API.send_direct_message(screen_name, text)
re = API.send_direct_message(id, text)
print re
```

got following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweetApi.py", line 36, in <module>
    re = API.send_direct_message(id, text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Text parameter is missing.', u'code': 38}]
```

What will be mistake done by me...???

I also have another problem related to tweepy, How can I moved to page two or got more followers in following code

```
i=1
user = API.get_user('Apple')
followers = API.followers(user.id,-1)
for follower in followers:
    print follower,'\t',i
    i=i+1
```

if I run the code I got only 5000 followers however if I use `user.followers_count` it gives *362705* followers (**This no. may be changes while You check it**) How can I see remaining followers

Thank You... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your first error, replace `re = API.send_direct_message(id, text)` with `re = API.send_direct_message(id, text=text)`. This function only works if you give it the message as a named parameter. The parameter name you need here is "text", so you might want to change your variable name to avoid confusion. Also, I just tried it, since you are sending a direct message, not a tweet, it will **not** be truncated to only the first 140 characters.

For your second question, this should do the trick, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431807/get-all-follower-ids-in-twitter-by-tweepy):

```
followers = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(API.followers, screen_name='Apple').pages():
    followers.extend(page)
    time.sleep(60) #this is here to slow down your requests and prevent you from hitting the rate limit and encountering a new error
print(followers)
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks For Your reply... :)