# How to parse twitter followers of a certain account?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, twitter

I am trying to parse followers` nicknames from a twitter account (https://twitter.com/oldLentach/followers).

This is how I detect the nicknames along with some unnecessary stuff, which can be easily filtered out afterward:

```
[el.get_attribute('href') for el in 
 browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div//a[@role="link"][@aria-haspopup="false"][@data-focusable="true"]')]
```

Then I scroll the page down to load new users and repeat the upper code:

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

However, the output is precisely the same as if I did not do any scrolls! (I checked that the scrolls work)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ended up finding an answer or not, but you might want to look into using tweepy.

There's a really great answer by user alecxe here on a similar question:
[Get All Follower IDs in Twitter by Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431807/get-all-follower-ids-in-twitter-by-tweepy)

Cheers!